# Can someone explain this C code?

Tags: c, string, char

Can someone explain this reverse sentence code for me? How does the first and the second looping works? What's the point of each of them?

```
main(){
    char arr[255], *p;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    gets(arr);

    for(p=arr; *p!='\0'; p++);

    for(p--; p>=arr; p--){
       printf("%c",*p);
    }
}
```

Input:

```
I love you
```

Output:

```
uoy evol I
```

Comment: First loop is used to get the address of the memory location of the end of the string which was typed by the user. The second loop is used to reverse the string from that point on.

Comment: Is has undefined behavior, as `p--` is undefined when `p` is `arr`. This means it may do anything.

Comment: What have you done by yourself to get the point yet?

Answer (score 2):

The code is basically printing in reverse the input array.

```
for(p=arr; *p!='\0'; p++);
```

Sets `p` as the last (relevant) element of the array (the null character)

```
  for(p--; p>=arr; p--){
      printf("%c",*p);
    }
```

starts from the last (none null) character and prints each one from last to first.

**Question for you:**

What happens if the input array is longet than 255 chars? (answer below)

<sub>[buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the input is `Hello World`. This gets stored in your buffer `arr` as

```
[H][e][l][l][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][\0]...
```

Your pointer is set to `arr`, hence the pointer points to `H`

```
[H][e][l][l][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][\0]...
 ^
 |
 p
```

The first loop advances (`p++`) until it meets the first null character (`\0`). It now looks like

```
[H][e][l][l][o][ ][W][o][r][l][d][\0]...
                                  ^
                                  |
                                  p
```

Now the second loop goes *back* (`p--`) until it reaches the first character again (actually, until the pointer equals the pointer to the beginning of the array), printing each character as it meets it. The first character `\0` however is ignored with the little `p--` here:

```
for(p--; p>=arr; p--)
    ^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The code looks clever, but it actually exhibits undefined behavior, which means the code may do anything.

The problem is the second loop:

```
for(p--; p>=arr; p--){
    printf("%c",*p);
}
```

What it's intended to do is to start `p` at the last character of the string (excluding the terminating `\0`, then keep decrementing it until all the characters of the string have been output in reverse order.

The problem is the termination condition: after the intended end of the loop, `p` is `arr`, and then `p--` subtracts one, and then `p >= arr` is false.

Unfortunately, an arithmetic operation on pointers may not result in a pointer that no longer points to the object (or one after the final object of an array), or it's undefined behavior.

That's what's happening here: `p--` causes `p` to be off the array, and all bets are off as to what happens next.

Here's a correct way to write the second loop:

```
for (int i = (p-arr)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    printf("%c", p[i]);
}
```

I'd probably write the entire code using indexes to completely avoid pointer arithmetic. Maybe something like this:

```
int i = 0;
// Find the terminating \0 byte
while(p[i])i++;
// Iterate backwards through the string, outputting characters along the way.
while(--i >= 0)putc(p[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Before explaining the code, I must say two things - first, the signature of the `main` function should be one of the following -

```
int main(void);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

and second, **do not use `gets`**. It's not safe to use. Use `fgets` instead. Now, coming to the code.

```
for(p = arr; *p != '\0'; p++) ;
```

In the above loop, `p` is assigned the base address of the array `arr`, i.e., the address of the first element of the array `arr`. The array `arr` contains a terminating null byte which means it is a string. The loop body is the null statement `;` which means `p` is incremented till the null byte is encountered, i.e., when the test `*p != '\0'` fails. In the `for` loop

```
for(p--; p >= arr; p--) {
   printf("%c",*p);
}
```

`p` is first decremented to point to the last character just before the null byte and then it is printed in each iteration till the condition `p >= arr` is `true`, i.e., till the first element of the array is reached. You should change your code to -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char arr[255], *p;

    printf("Enter string:\n");
    fgets(arr, sizeof arr, stdin);
    for(p = arr; *p! = '\0'; p++) 
        ;  // the null statement

    for(p--; p >= arr; p--)
       printf("%c", *p);

    return 0;        
}
```